# Do the file descriptors get lost when remounting a file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

If I remount the file system on /home with:

```
mount -o,remount /home
```

will the open file descriptors be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  That's pretty much the whole point of `-o remount`.